# Set a block when something happens

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Okay, so I'm trying to get a block to change when something happens. I have the command `execute as @a[scores={hunger=6}] run say you cant do that anymore`  to detect when your hunger is low.

I also have `setblock -308 4 46 minecraft:stone` just to place the block the player mines

What I'm needing, is when your hunger bar is at 0, the block changes to bedrock and shows a message **You cant do that anymore**

so far, just having the execute hunger command, I have it on a repeating command block, it only shows when your hunger is at 0, but it spams the chat instead.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to tag the player who has the hunger 0 and not act on it. So you would:

- Execute the Say command as a `not tagged` and `hungry` player
- Execute the tag add
- Remove the tag if he isn't hungry

And they would look like something along the lines of:

```
/execute as @a[scores={hunger=0},tag=!hungry] run say you cant do that anymore
/execute as @a[scores={hunger=0}] run tag @s add hungry
/execute as @a[scores={hunger=1..}] run tag @s remove hungry
```

the `!` in front of `hungry` will negate the tag, so it would be read as "Not hungry"

Also, not that `tellraw` would be more appropriate here as `say` will be shown to all players.